# Has my Pakistan Origin Card (POC) expired or not? How to apply for a POC renewal?

Tags: pakistani-citizens, pakistan

As per date on my [Pakistan Origin Card (POC)](https://documentationnow.com/pakistan-origin-card-poc-card/) , it expired in May 2018, but when I try to submit application for renewal online, it says your POC is not expired and my application does not get through. What do I do now?

Answer (score 5):

**I hope the following information will be helpful for all who are trying to get their POC renewed.**

I called them today on the number +92 51 111 786 100. The call center advised me to choose "modify POC" instead of "renew POC". That has worked out for me. Please keep the following documents/information handy before starting the online process.

1. Scan of your existing  POC
2. Scan of your current valid foreign passport
3. Name, Contact number and CNIC of a Pakistani citizen who
   can verify your details.
4. A printer to print the signature form
   which has to be signed by the applicant during the process, and
5. a scanner or a digital camera to scan the printed form after filling
   in the required information and signing it

That is how it works. **Their web interface is not really stable I had to start editing my application about 10 times as the Website kept on crashing**. In that case you have to log in and choose **Existing Application** from the top menu [image: This is how the top menu looks like!]

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer to the posted question. But it may still be helpful as I am facing the same problem. Looks like they have some programming error regarding the comparison of dates. I'll call them tomorrow morning as they are not available at their service number +92 51 111 786 100 at this time.

By the way, for JoErNanO and others who may have the same question, a POC is a sort of document issued by the Government of Pakistan that enables persons of Pakistani origin to travel back to Pakistan without having to get a visa.

Comment: "call them on [that number]" sounds like an answer to me!